# SAML Client implementation for Android?

Tags: android, saml, opensaml

Is there a sample application which I can refer for SAML interactions on Android?
Anyone successfully ported/used OpenSAML on Android ?

I am trying to write a simple app which would (instead of browser redirection) use native APIs to carry out SAML authentication.

Also some pointers to test environment where I can test SAML clients would help.

Comment: OpenSAML may have issues: http://www.nds.rub.de/research/publications/BreakingSAML

Comment: anybody was able to implement it in android

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you need to authenticate your mobile app users against a SAML 2.0 IDP, then you would NOT build this into Android (or iOS). Best practice would be to have your mobile app use OAuthv2 and exchange a SAML Response generated by the IDP for your local SP/AS OAuth token. Essentially, the application would launch the WebView browser w/in your application to carry out the SAML Web SSO profile which would result in your AS giving your mobile app an OAuth token. It's not required to use OAuth in this type of scenario, but it will add security & standard support to your mobile application.

Ping Identity [Note: I do work for Ping] has done a ton of work to make SAML/OAuth quick and easy for SaaS Providers to implement (over 250 SaaS Providers and growing). Check out https://www.pingidentity.com/products/pingfederate/secure-mobile-access.cfm

HTH =-
Ian

Comment: I an in need of writing a native android solution to authenticate against enterprise services using SAML.

Comment: So a SP app server is mandatory for a mobile app? There is no way without an SP?

Comment: Link is broken.

Comment: Ian, my client uses Ping.  Can you provide a link to *documentation* on how to implement the Android side of Single-Sign On using SAML 2.0?

Comment: This Q&A is almost 7 years old. I'd suggest reframing your question with more information about your specific use case as a new question.

Comment: @Ian actually the same question still applies.  Do you still work for Ping?  Can you write a new answer here?  Preferably just provide a link to official documentation.  The client refuses to offer anything but SAML 2.0 for the app we have to build for them.

Comment: @VishJ : Were you able to implement the SAML authentication in Android app succesfully? If yes, kindly share the details.