# SAML client for Android?

Tags: java, android, saml, shibboleth, opensaml

I'm working on a project which needs to parse some data from some protected web pages. In order to gain the access those pages, I have to overcome a SAML authetication form (Shibboleth).
Is there someone who was able to implement this standard in Android (Java)?
I already read this thread: [SAML Client implementation for Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11929158/saml-client-implementation-for-android) 
but it doesn't give me a good solution. In fact, I need to *get the data of some protected web pages* in order to parse it, not to let the user to see the content of such pages. Therefore logging in through a WebView is not what I really need..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research, I ended up building it on my own. 
I carefully followed every redirect, and took note of every cookie created, edited or deleted (Opera, with its in-built option which allows to switch off redirects was the key). 
The result was a flow which then I replicated in a package *ad hoc*: the SetUpConnection class, whose task was connecting to the host and keeping track of the cookies. SAML class, which replicated the SAML flow, and finally the Main class, from which I can gather useful information.

Hope it helps.

Comment: can you post your solution

Answer (score 1):

I think OpenSAML is your best bet for handling the SAML part and then maybe HttpClient for the things you normally will do in a browser. But there will be quite som work implementing this. There is nothing lightweight about SAML.

OpenSAML is just a library helping with processing of SAML messages so it is probably good for very customised stuff like this.