# SAML2 authentication on android app

Tags: android, liferay, saml, saml-2.0

I have an mobile application on android that connects to a Liferay Portal backend. Is there a solution to login from the android app using SAML2? The Liferay SDK doesn't offer saml support. Or can anyone help me with some resources that I can use to accomplish this?

Thank you!

I attached bellow more details about what I'm doing now.
Because there isn't support for SAML on mobile I use a webview to access the login page where the users enters email and password. After login is successful I want to sync the cookies from the webview with the http client to be able to make request to a API from native code.

When the page is finished loading I call the method to sync my cookies in a

```
CookieStore from a DataHolder class
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        Log.d(Consts.DONI_APP_DEBUG_TAG, "---> Page start loading: " + url);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        syncCookiesFromAppCookieManager(url);
    }
});

public void syncCookiesFromAppCookieManager(String url) {

    CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
    if (cookieManager == null) return;

    RFC2109Spec cookieSpec = new RFC2109Spec();
    String rawCookieHeader = null;
    try {
        URL parsedURL = new URL(url);

        //Extract Set-Cookie header value from Android app CookieManager for this URL
        rawCookieHeader = cookieManager.getCookie(parsedURL.getHost());

        if (rawCookieHeader == null) return;

        //Convert Set-Cookie header value into Cookies w/in HttpClient CookieManager
        int port = parsedURL.getPort() == -1 ?
                parsedURL.getDefaultPort() : parsedURL.getPort();

        CookieOrigin cookieOrigin = new CookieOrigin( parsedURL.getHost(),
                port,
                "/",
                false);

        String[] sCookies = rawCookieHeader.split(";");
        List<Cookie> appCookies = new ArrayList<Cookie>();
        for(String c : sCookies){
            String[] cc = c.split("=");
            DataHolder.cookieStore.addCookie(cookieSpec.parse(
                new BasicHeader("set-cookie", c),
                cookieOrigin).get(0));
        }

        CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // Handle Error
        Log.d(Consts.DONI_APP_DEBUG_TAG, "Error 1!");
    } catch (MalformedCookieException e) {
        // Handle Error
        Log.d(Consts.DONI_APP_DEBUG_TAG, "Error 2!");
    }
}
```

After all this, I attach the cookiestore to the httpClient and make the request:
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
httpClient.setCookieStore(DataHolder.cookieStore);

```
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
httpGet.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

try {
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

    HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
    if(resEntity != null){
        String responseStr = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity).trim();
        Log.d("LOG", "Response: " + responseStr);
    }
}catch (IOException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I test the httpClient's cookies before the request and it shows they are attached but the request returns the login html page not the response from the api. 
I also tested this with 2 different webviews. I login in the first webview and after that I load the api url in the second webview and it works.

What am I doing wrong? I also noticed that there is a lot of classes that are deprecated but this are the only resources related to this that I found on other forums.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Welcome to the StackOverflow. In general, questions asking for recommendations are not much welcome here and are usually closed. Still if you are looking for SAML library for Android, then maybe our SecureBlackbox will do the job.

Comment: It appears that Lifreray supports [SAML as an SP](https://www.liferay.com/web/armin.dahncke/blog/-/blogs/setting-up-liferay-portal-6-1-ee-as-a-sp)... Have you set that up? Do you have an IdP?  I'm not sure if it will spawn a webview (or whatever Android calls it) to support a SAML Authn...

Comment: Yes, the SAML with SP and IdP is installed the backend and it works on webapplication. But now I need to login from the mobile app and make calls to the api.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SAML client for Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15254216/saml-client-for-android)